# Why does SMTP-Server give "500 5.5.2 Error: bad syntax" in response DATA?

Tags: email, smtp, postfix-mta

I am writing a tool to send mails. Unfortunately after the `DATA`-Command has been processed, the server responds with an error.
I can stare at the msg as long as I want, I don't see anything that jumps out. But maybe I'm missing the obvious.
Here's a complete log of that session: *(CRLF causes blank line in the log, but for authenticity I left it in)*

I also checked postfix´ log, but there was nothing about errors related to this msg.

```
cmd="AUTH LOGIN"
rc=" 0  CLT00000004  Block  334 VXNlcm5hbWU6    

 "                                              
cmd="***"
rc=" 0  CLT00000004  Block  334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6    

 "                                              
cmd="***"
rc=" 0  CLT00000004  Block  235 2.7.0 Authentication successful    

 "                                                                 
cmd="NOOP"
rc=" 0  CLT00000004  Block  250 2.0.0 Ok    

 "                                          
cmd="MAIL FROM: <***>"
rc=" 0  CLT00000004  Block  250 2.1.0 Ok    

 "                                          
cmd="RCPT TO: <***>"
rc=" 0  CLT00000004  Block  250 2.1.5 Ok    

 "                                          
cmd="RCPT TO: <***>"
rc=" 0  CLT00000004  Block  250 2.1.5 Ok    

 "                                          
cmd="DATA"
rc=" 0  CLT00000004  Block  354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>    

 "                                                                 
cmd="Subject: [TEST] Here it is

MIME-Version:1.0

Reply-To:<***>

From:<***>

Date: Fri, 29 Nov 2019 10:05:02 +0100

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed

Content-Transfer-Encoding:7bit



Contributed by: MBaas <***>

first line





and more text
with a lone "." @ EOM




..



.

"
rc=" 0  CLT00000004  Block  250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4668A16C05CB                                 

500 5.5.2 Error: bad syntax                                                                      

 "
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duh, the problem was that the msg-content ended with CRLF.CRLF - and I added another CRLF :((

After removing that, it all worked nicely :)

Comment: Thanks, I ran into exactly the same problem!